# Flutter/Dart: Customize Bottom Navigation Bar height

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to customize `BottomNavigationBar`'s height?

I currently have a `BottomNavigationBar` with tabs to taps/swipe navigate, however the default height (even after reducing the text and icon) is too high.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    title: Text( 'RefLog', style: Styles.headerLarge ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.list),
        onPressed: () {},
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        children: _children,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab( text: 'One', icon: Icon(Icons.import_contacts, size: 20.0) ),
          Tab( text: 'Two', icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 20.0) ),
          Tab( text: 'Three', icon: Icon(Icons.record_voice_over, size: 20.0) ),
        ],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
        labelColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white30,
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Comment: Looks like the height is hardcoded. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e6d216cca85428b6f105b1a66409c190a7e4619a/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tabs.dart#L23

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can wrapper bottomNavigationBar by SizedBox,

```
bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(height: 58, child: //some widget )
```

Comment: What if the height of 58" is too large for small devices or too small for large devices?

Comment: Use MediaQuery to get the height of the device. Try various heights of bottom bar to see which looks nice. Express the size decided in terms of percentage of height of device. screenHeight * constant = bottom nav bar height. constant = sizeChosen / screenHeight of device which  you used for deciding

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an overflowing layout when trying to wrap a BottomNavigationBar in a SizedBox.

Answer (score 10):

I set `BottomNavigationBar( selectedFontSize: 0.0, unselectedFontSize: 0.0)`. And then I wrap `BottomNavigationBar` widget with `SizedBox( height: 50)`.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, the `BottomNavigationBar`'s height can't be override, my solution was resized the icons using **`SizedBox`**, it does decrease the height, other final solution was update the font size of title property, this my example:

```
new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon:new SizedBox(
                child: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Image.asset("assets/images/icon_ar.png"),
                    onPressed: () {}),
                width: 38,
                height: 38,
              ),
              title: new Text("", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 0),))
```

This does my `BottomNavigationBar` had a size standard in both platforms.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own widget

```
 Widget customBottomNavigationBar(BuildContext context){
    double myHeight =100.0;//Your height HERE
    return SizedBox(
    height: myHeight,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child:TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab( text: 'One', icon: Icon(Icons.import_contacts, size: 20.0) ),
              Tab( text: 'Two', icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 20.0) ),
              Tab( text: 'Three', icon: Icon(Icons.record_voice_over, size: 20.0) ),
            ],
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white30,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          ),
    );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    title: Text( 'RefLog', style: Styles.headerLarge ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.list),
        onPressed: () {},
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        children: _children,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: customBottomNavigationBar(context),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to customize BottomNavigationBar's height?

No

> Why?

Because the developers of that widget didn't give us any controls to play with it.

> But how can I achieve it?

[Read this article](https://medium.com/@larsenthomasj/from-flutter-to-flight-5-a-custom-navigation-bar-5e01c7483317)

Also, if you'll prepare custom `BottomNavBar` you'll have to take care of the listeners on your own. It's not just creating a `Container` with a `Row` of `IconButtons`.

[Update] By 'no' I mean [BottomNavigationBar class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

There can be workarounds, as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: Article no longer exists. 

The more I learn flutter the worst it seems. Widgets are complex and inflexible.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for bringing this up. Also, if you find flutter daunting, I would suggest you to pick either of the native framework (android or iOS) and then work your way through Flutter. Jumping straight into Hybrid framework doesn’t really help. :)

Comment: You can wrapper bottomNavigationBar by SizedBox,

Comment: Hi @MrSalesi please read the `[Update]` on the answer. This answer was in addition to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

play with the selectedfontsize and unselectedfont size properties. I set both of mine to 1.0 and it seems to have reduced the extra padding on top and bottom of the nav bar thus reducing its height

BottomNavigationBar(
iconSize: kIconSize20,
selectedFontSize: 1.0,
unselectedFontSize: 1.0,
...

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter 3.7.8**

Remember there are two bottom nav bar: Material & Cupertino.

For **Cupertino** just use the height property

```
// Standard iOS 10 tab bar height.
const double _kTabBarHeight = 50.0;
```

Example

```
CupertinoTabBar(
   activeColor: LumiantDefaultTheme.primary.shade700,
   inactiveColor: LumiantDefaultTheme.grey.shade400,
   items: bottomNavBarItems,
   currentIndex: selectedTabIndex,
   onTap: onTabSelected,
   height: 66,
 ),
```

For **Material** bottom nav bar height:
That's how its calculated:

```
constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: kBottomNavigationBarHeight + additionalBottomPadding)
```

The height of the bottom navigation bar.

```
double kBottomNavigationBarHeight = 56.0;
additionalBottomPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom = 0;
```

But will not be 0 if SafeArea at the bottom is used. So do a bit of math.

So as an example wrap it with SizedBox

```
bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: 66,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          xxx
          xxx
          xxx
            ),
          ),
```